# How to recover the type of a function pointer at runtime

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, type-erasure

In the code I register one or multiple function pointer in a manager class.

In this class I have a map that maps the argument types of the function to said function. It may look like so: `std::map< std::vector<std::type_index> , void*>`

```
template<typename Ret, typename... Args>
void Register(Ret(*function)(Args...)) {
    void* v = (void*)function;
    // recursively build type vector and add to the map
}
```

At runtime the code gets calls (from an external script) with an arbitrary number of arguments. These arguments can be read as primitive data types or as custom types that will be specified at compile time.

---

With every call from the script, I have to find out which function to call, and then call it. The former is easy and already solved (filling a vector with `type_index` in a loop), but I can't think of a solution for the latter.

My first approach was using variadic templates in recursion with an added template argument for each read type - but this turned out to be impossible since templates are constructed at compile time, and the arbitrary number of arguments is read at runtime.

Without variadic templates however, I don't see any possibility to achieve this. I considered `boost::any` instead of `void*`, but I didn't see how that would solve the need to cast back to the original type. I also thought of using `std::function` but that would be a templated type, so it could not be stored in a map for functions with different arguments.

---

*(If it's unclear what I'm asking, think of [LuaBinds](https://github.com/Oberon00/luabind) possibility to [register overloaded functions](http://oberon00.github.io/luabind/functions.html#overloaded-functions). I tried to understand how it's implemented there (without variadic templates, pre-C++11), but to no avail.)*

Comment: Maybe? http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/46473/dynamically-call-lambda-based-on-stream-input-try-3  Not sure if that is similar or not.  I think you're probably heading in the direction of writing an interpreter.. Not sure though.

Comment: just in passing, posix requires conversion between `void*` and function pointer, but standard C and C++ do not support that.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Thanks for your input, I did not know that, though [it compiled without errors](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ba6271eb110648a5). A similar (conform) approach would be storing a pointer to the virtual base class of a templated class that stores the actual function pointer, though that would end up with the same problem requiring the same casting. I'm not at all set on the `void*`/casting solution! It was just what I was able to come up with.

Comment: I think you're looking for *type erasure*. The simplest implementation here AFAIK is to use a wrapper function template which stores the actual type in its template parameters: `template<class T> void wrapper(void* p) { static_cast<T*>(p)->whatever(); } void(*f)(void*) = wrapper<MyFirstType>; f = wrapper<MySecondType>;` etc.

Comment: Are you not replicating the functionality of `std::function` and `std::bind`?

Comment: @SteveLorimer I don't want to replace anything that's already there, I'm only trying to write the handler for the script calls. A solution with `std::bind` and `std::function` would be great! I just haven't considered `std::bind` before since it wasn't mentioned anywhere in the research I did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you had the arguments in a `vector` of some kind, and a known function (fully).

You can call this.  Call the function that does this `invoke`.

Next, work out how to do this for `template<class... Args>`.  Augment `invoke`.

So you have written:

```
typedef std::vector<run_time_stuff> run_time_args;
template<class... Args>
void invoke( void(*func)(Args...), run_time_args rta )
```

at this point.  Note that we know the types of the argument.  I do not claim the above is easy to write, but I have faith you can figure it out.

Now we wrap things up:

```
template<class...Args>
std::function<void(run_time_args)> make_invoker(void(*func)(Args...)){
  return [func](run_time_args rta){
    invoke(func, rta);
  };
}
```

and now instead of `void*` you store `std::function<void(run_time_args)>` -- invokers.  When you add the function pointers to the mechanism you use `make_invoker` instead of casting to `void*`.

Basically, at the point where we have the type info, we store how to use it.  Then where we want to use it, we use the stored code!

Writing `invoke` is another problem.  It will probably involve the indexes trick.

Suppose we support two kinds of arguments -- `double` and `int`.  The arguments at run time are then loaded into a `std::vector< boost::variant<double, int> >` as our `run_time_args`.

Next, let us extend the above `invoke` function to return an error in the case of parameter type mismatch.

```
enum class invoke_result {
  everything_ok,
  error_parameter_count_mismatch,
  parameter_type_mismatch,
};
typedef boost::variant<int,double> c;
typedef std::vector<run_time_stuff> run_time_args;
template<class... Args>
invoke_result invoke( void(*func)(Args...), run_time_args rta );
```

now some boilerplate for the indexes trick:

```
template<unsigned...Is>struct indexes{typedef indexes type;};
template<unsigned Max,unsigned...Is>struct make_indexes:make_indexes<Max-1, Max-1,Is...>{};
template<unsigned...Is>struct make_indexes<0,Is...>:indexes<Is...>{};
template<unsigned Max>using make_indexes_t=typename make_indexes<Max>::type;
```

With that, we can write an invoker:

```
namespace helpers{
  template<unsigned...Is, class... Args>
  invoke_result invoke( indexes<Is...>, void(*func)(Args...), run_time_args rta ) {
    typedef void* pvoid;
    if (rta.size() < sizeof...(Is))
      return invoke_result::error_parameter_count_mismatch;
    pvoid check_array[] = { ((void*)boost::get<Args>( rta[Is] ))... };
    for( pvoid p : check_array )
      if (!p)
        return invoke_result::error_parameter_type_mismatch;
    func( (*boost::get<Args>(rts[Is]))... );
  }
}

template<class... Args>
invoke_result invoke( void(*func)(Args...), run_time_args rta ) {
  return helpers::invoke( make_indexes_t< sizeof...(Args) >{}, func, rta );
}
```

And that should work when `func`'s args exactly match the ones passed in inside `run_time_args`.

Note that I was fast and loose with failing to `std::move` that `std::vector` around.  And that the above doesn't support implicit type conversion.  And I didn't compile any of the above code, so it is probably littered with typos.

Comment: You can also use [boost::fusion::invoke](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/functional/invocation/functions/invoke.html) :)

Comment: @Drax not sure how to use that with a run time typed collection of arguments.  The forward sequence it uses seems to a compile time collection of arguments at first glance.

Comment: As the OP stated in his comment to [@Steve Lorimer's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23484197/1147772) : "the argument types are known at compile time", only their value are unkown, and these types are exactly your template parameter called `Args` in your `invoke` function template. The sequence used by `boost::fusion` are hybrid sequences with the compile time information being the types and the runtime informations being the value, which suits this use case quite well :)

Comment: I don't know if I understood the code right, but doesn't this require holding a templated type? How do I store functions with different signatures in a map this way?

Comment: @AdamS You store `std::function`s in the map.  The signature of this `std::function` is always the same.  We **create** the `std::function` so that it stores the function pointer, and knows how to unpack the `std::vector` of "generic" arguments into the function call.  Because we know the signature of the function pointer at the point we create the `std::function`, we can write that code.  I tried to walk you through the steps -- can you write the `invoke` function?  Ie, can you call a **fixed** function without looking it up?  Then, can you write it as a `template` on that function type?

Comment: @Yakk Sorry, I'm probably just being dumb; I ought to store `std::function<void(run_time_args)>` in my map where `run_time_args` is `std::vector<run_time_stuff>` - but what is `run_time_stuff` at this point? I can't hardcode the supported types however.

Comment: @AdamS I do not know how your run time arguments are encoded, you have not told me.  When you get arguments from the script, how are they passed to you?  Not directly as the "right" C++ types I presume.  You'll get a `void*`, or a string, or something else.  The `std::vector<run_time_stuff>` is a placeholder for whatever that is.  Then you write an `invoke` that, given a function pointer with full argument type information already there, it calls it using whatever the script provides.  That is `invoke`, and I cannot write it for you as your interface from the script is still secret.

Comment: @AdamS or, in short, suppose the only function you could call from the script was called `foo`.  It takes an `int` and a `double` (and, if ambitious, a `std::string`).  Ignoring your "map" problem -- as there is only one function, and its signature and name is known and fixed -- please demonstrate the code that lets the script call `foo`.  That is almost all there is to `invoke`, and I cannot write it for you, because I do not know how your script gives you arguments.

Comment: @Yakk But the map *is* the problem - If it was only of one type, I could just write a templated wrapper and store a std::function in the first place. The way I get the arguments doesn't really matter, it could be just a string containing them, in reality they're read with the Lua api though. The issue I'm having is storing functions of various signatures in a class with a single map, each call `Register` registers a different signature; That's why I tried to use `void*`. My `foo` in the script should be callable with everything I `Register` for it, each signature should call another function.

Comment: @Yakk I'm sorry if we talk past each other, I've been a bit tired the last few days.

Comment: @adamS No, map is *your* problem. My problem is you won't provide me with the code *without* the map. The way you get the arguments **is the only thing I do not have** that you can provide to solve your problem. This is why I asked for it, repeatedly, implicitly and explicitly. If you won't do this, I will not help you. Write code that calls `void foo(int, double)` from your scripting engine. That is probably all I need. I attempted to give you an answer based around `std::vector<run_time_stuff>` which represents whatever source you have for args, but that failed, so I must be concrete.

Comment: @Yakk I just mentioned that I read them with the Lua API... But here's some code: [http://pastebin.com/BXyYYUa2](http://pastebin.com/BXyYYUa2). Here's how I've read it in an older version where only one signature was supported (types (T...) known beforehand in a templated wrapper class): [http://pastebin.com/PavCpFpf](http://pastebin.com/PavCpFpf). The last one returned a tuple with the args and I had code that called a function with said args from the tuple.

Comment: @AdamS I see no function named `foo`.  I thought I was clear.  **call `foo(int, double)`**, getting the arguments from the scripting engine.  The code you provided is partial, and I'm out of patience reading tea leaves.

Comment: @Yakk There is no such function named foo - the call is mapped to a static dispatch function. The same dispatch function for each and every function in the script. `foo()` is mapped to `dispatch(lua_State*)`. Just as `bar()`. Regardless of the arguments. Each function however holds a pointer to a class instance, `foo` a different instance than `bar`, but in each instance I need to have a map with different signatures mapped to different functions. So `foo(int, int)` dispatches to the same instance as `foo(int, bool)` and the arguments are received with the code I already gave you. (contd.)

Comment: This is the complete, now stripped down code without the map from the OP: http://pastebin.com/1LkV0CFx. It won't tell you any more than my previous link.

Comment: @AdamS http://ideone.com/B8fRw1 is `invoke` (with stub functions, and maybe wrong index, etc).  Use `typedef lua_state* run_time_args`.  Store `std::function< void(run_time_args) >` in your map (instead of your `void*`).  Use `make_invoker` (as written above) to turn a function pointer into that.  Am I missing something?

Comment: You're great. I'll give you a few extra reputation for your patience.

Answer (score 1):

I was messing around with variadic templates a few weeks ago and came up with a solution that might help you.

#### DELEGATE.H

```
template <typename ReturnType, typename ...Args>
class BaseDelegate
{
public:
    BaseDelegate()
        : m_delegate(nullptr)
    {

    }

    virtual ReturnType Call(Args... args) = 0;
    BaseDelegate* m_delegate;
};

template <typename ReturnType = void, typename ...Args>
class Delegate : public BaseDelegate<ReturnType, Args...>
{
public:
    template <typename ClassType>
    class Callee : public BaseDelegate
    {
    public:
        typedef ReturnType (ClassType::*FncPtr)(Args...);
    public:
        Callee(ClassType* type, FncPtr function)
            : m_type(type)
            , m_function(function)
        {

        }

        ~Callee()
        {

        }

        ReturnType Call(Args... args)
        {
            return (m_type->*m_function)(args...);
        }

    protected:
        ClassType* m_type;
        FncPtr m_function;
    };

public:
    template<typename T>
    void RegisterCallback(T* type, ReturnType (T::*function)(Args...))
    {
        m_delegate = new Callee<T>(type, function);
    }

    ReturnType Call(Args... args)
    {
        return m_delegate->Call(args...);
    }
};
```

#### MAIN.CPP

```
class Foo
{
public:
    int Method(int iVal)
    {
        return iVal * 2;
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char* args)
{
    Foo foo;
    typedef Delegate<int, int> MyDelegate;

    MyDelegate m_delegate;
    m_delegate.RegisterCallback(&foo, &Foo::Method);

    int retVal = m_delegate.Call(10);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How does this help with the OP's multiple signature problem?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if your requirements will allow this, but you could possibly just use `std::function` and `std::bind`.

The below solution makes the following assumptions:

- You know the functions you want to call and their arguments
- The functions can have any signature, and any number of arguments
- You want to use type erasure to be able to store these functions and arguments, and call them all at a later point in time

Here is a working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <list>

// list of all bound functions
std::list<std::function<void()>> funcs;

// add a function and its arguments to the list
template<typename Ret, typename... Args, typename... UArgs>
void Register(Ret(*Func)(Args...), UArgs... args)
{
    funcs.push_back(std::bind(Func, args...));
}

// call all the bound functions
void CallAll()
{
    for (auto& f : funcs)
        f();
}

////////////////////////////
// some example functions
////////////////////////////

void foo(int i, double d)
{
    std::cout << __func__ << "(" << i << ", " << d << ")" << std::endl;
}

void bar(int i, double d, char c, std::string s)
{
    std::cout << __func__ << "(" << i << ", " << d << ", " << c << ", " << s << ")" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    Register(&foo, 1, 2);
    Register(&bar, 7, 3.14, 'c', "Hello world");

    CallAll();
}
```

Comment: This looks good, and `bind` seems like a step in the right direction. However, only the argument types are known at compile time; the arguments are not - they are given at run time (the functions can be called numerous times with different arguments), so they can't be bound in `Register`.

Comment: @AdamS - will all functions have the same signature? (ie: same number of arguments, same type of arguments)

Comment: No, and that's the problem I'm facing. Any number of functions with different signatures can be registered. The script will call `function(100, 10, 'foo')` and from this information I have to call one of the functions (the one fitting the signature). See the link in my original question for a good example.